# What is the best way to log the client identifier in the logs written by a SimpleSocketServer attached to SocketAppenders in log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

So, we have a cluster of servers that run the same application. For logging, we use `log4j` and the `Logger`s used are attached to `ConsoleAppender`s that ultimately log the data to local log files. To aggregate logs from all of these servers, I also have a `SocketAppender` attached to each of these loggers. A `SimpleSocketServer` runs on another remote host configured with this `SocketAppender` that will consume the `LoggingEvent`s and format them with the `PatternLayout` specified in the configuration file supplied to that process.

Since this remote server can consume only the `LoggingEvent`s sent to it from the clients, I cannot apply a formatter before sending them across and so I cannot log the identifier of the client host that is sending the request. Ideally, I want to be able to log the IP of the client so that I can pinpoint a host with a particular issue from the logs. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: "attached to ConsoleAppenders that ultimately log the data to local log files" why not use a file-appender directly?

Comment: "the identifier of the client host" you mean the domain name or IP address of the host that reported the message to be logged by the remote host?

Comment: @Raedwald yes, i mean the client that generated the LoggingEvent to the remote SimpleSocketServer host.